# Shuffle bag with repetition constraint

Tags: algorithm, random

I'm looking for an algorithm to randomize a set of items with length `n`, where there might be multiples (1 to `m`) of each item. An additional constraint is that the same item may not appear within `k` items of the previous one.

You may assume `n` is well under 100, and there always is a solution, i.e. `m` as well as `k` are small. You can also change the input to a list of <item, frequency> pairs if that helps.

To give a bit of context, assume I'm generating missions in a game and have a set of goals to choose from. Some goals may appear multiple times (e.g. "kill the boss"), but should not be close to each other, so simply shuffling the "bag" is no good.

I could shuffle the list, then iterate over it while keeping track of item intervals, starting with a new shuffle if it fails the test, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution that should also be compact, practical and easily implemented with e.g. C, C++ or JavaScript. In other words it should not rely on special language features or standard library functions that I might not understand or could find hard time implementing. However, you may assume the most common list operations such as sorting and shuffling are available.

Answer (score 2):

If you want uniform probabilities over the set of valid outcomes, my hunch is that the rejection scheme you proposed (shuffle and then restart if the arrangement is bad) is going to be the easiest to code correctly, understand, read, and maintain as well as probably fairly close to the fastest, assuming that the numbers are such that most permutations are valid.

Here's another simple approach, though, based on greedily choosing valid values and hoping you don't knock yourself out. It's not at all guaranteed to find a solution if there are many invalid permutations (high `m` and `k`).

```
shuffled = list of length n
not_inserted = {0, 1, ..., n-1}
for each item i, frequency m_i, nearness constraint k_i:
    valid = not_inserted
    do m_i times:
        choose an index j from valid
        shuffled[j] = i
        not_inserted.remove(j)
        valid.remove(j-k_i, j-k_i+1, ..., j, ..., j+k_i)
```

If `valid` is ever empty, the partial solution you've built up is bad, and you'll probably have to restart. I'm guessing that failures will be less likely if you do the loop in order of decreasing `m_i`.

I'm not sure about how often this approach fails in comparison to the sorting/rejecting approach (it'd be interesting to implement and run it for some numbers...). I'd guess that it might be faster in situations where `k` is moderately high, but usually slower, because shuffles are really fast for `n << 100`.

Comment: Took me a while to understand the pseudo code, but it looks like a nifty solution in the trial and error category.